# Twitter button not tweeting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have a Random Quote Generator (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgqWgo) and when trying to tweet a quote, I get the following result:

[image]

I am not linking my quote correctly I assume in my function. Being new to JavaScript it is hard to tell what though. I have searched extensively on this and can't seem to find a solution.

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 buttons">
                        <a class="twitter-share-button" href="http://twitter.com/share" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="tweetIt()"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="newQuote()">Quote</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div id="quoteDisplay" class="writing">
                            <!-- Quotes here -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var quotes = [
    "There is nothing to writing. All you do is sit down at a typewriter and bleed.",
    "Happiness in intelligent people is the rarest thing I know.",
    "The world breaks everyone, and afterward, some are strong at the broken places."
]
function newQuote() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
};

$(".twitter-share-button").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + randomNumber);
  });
```

Comment: Since you placed the Twitter button withing an <a> element, the target is overriding your actual link in the javascript. Twitter is defaulting the text to the URL you are coming from, which is: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=&original_referer=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that is being used in your code, is the one in the `<a>` tag.

You don't want that. That link has no data being passed in, therefore twitter is defaulting the URL as `twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=&original_referer=` which produces the text as the URL you are coming from. (In your case it's your local).

There's no need to wrap the twitter `button` an the `<a>` tag since you are using the `oncick() function.`

The following code seems to do what you are trying to accomplish.

**First modify your `HTML` as follows:**

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 buttons">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="tweetIt()">Tweet</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="newQuote()">Quote</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div id="quoteDisplay" class="writing">
                            <!-- Quotes here -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**And your `.js` should look like this:**

```
var quotes = [
    "There is nothing to writing. All you do is sit down at a typewriter and bleed.",
    "Happiness in intelligent people is the rarest thing I know.",
    "The world breaks everyone, and afterward, some are strong at the broken places."
]
function newQuote() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
};

function tweetIt(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + quotes[randomNumber]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. Helped me with a issue I have been struggling with for a while in a clean and simple way.